# Selected text in input field when bootstrap popover open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Have this form

```
<div tabindex="0" class="image-copy-to-clipboard image-copy-to-clipboard-icon" role="button" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus"
       title="Press Ctrl+C to copy page ID" data-html="true"
       data-content="<form><input type='text' placeholder='' value='#{{page.Id}} : {{page.Title}}' autofocus /></form>"></div>
```

How i can do selected text in input field when popover opens?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery something like

```
$(function () {
    $(".image-copy-to-clipboard")
        .popover()
        .open(function () {
            $('form input').select();
        });
});
```

**[JQuery's .select()](http://api.jquery.com/select/)**

> The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text
>   selection inside it. This event is limited to input `type="text"` fields
>   and `textarea` boxes.